# Do you use any GoogleMaps Api PHP wrapper class/libarary/script to plot maps?

Tags: php, google-maps

I want to display google maps (mutliple markers etc) and just found that there is one paid solution "GMap 2.3" for PHP. I was looking for an open source solution. Do you guys code using Google Maps API functions or use any wrapper script? What are some good links for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just use the google maps api. Several months ago I coded up a combination google maps / weather underground ajax data source for creating user-specific weather reports. curl was used on the php side for acting as a proxy for the weather data. the google map side really didn't need any php at all. It really just relies on javascript.

Try doing it without the paid libraries, chances are you'll find it's easier than you expect.

Comment: Yes, thinking of the same. Just was looking if any good solutions available. Thankx.

Answer (score 0):

This is the api wrapper i use

http://www.phpinsider.com/php/code/GoogleMapAPI/

it works very well and it's open source

Comment: I did visit this page, but its of year 2007. I was just thinking if there are relatively newer solutions. Thanks for your answer, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

We're updating the PHP Google Map API class (mentioned previously) to use the new V3 of the Google Maps JS APIs - you can get the updated project files at http://code.google.com/p/php-google-map-api

Answer (score -1):

I use [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) and the [Gmap](http://drupal.org/project/gmap)/[Location](http://drupal.org/project/location) modules. They're quite powerful in concert and can handle different marker engines, including clustering.